# Какой предлог написать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

"Уволен на пенсию в должности / с должности инспектора учебного отдела" — как правильно и где это регламентировано?

Answer (score 2):

При отправлении человека на пенсию важно подчеркнуть занимаемую им должность (для соответствующих начислений). Назначают *НА должность*, работают *В должности*. На ум приходит аналогия с военными: *вышел в отставку **в** звании полковника*. В словосочетании "*уволен с должности*" мерещится что-то карательное. Я бы написала "Уволен на пенсию в должности инспектора учебного отдела", тем самым подчеркивая, что за человеком остается некий статус (сообразно должности, которую он занимал). У военных ведь уволенный в запас в звании полковника остается полковником.

Чем употребление предлога в данном случае может быть регламентировано? Думаю, ничем. Ну, или какой-нибудь инструкцией по делопроизводству.