# Состоящее на/в должности

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какой предлог употребить: «лицо, состоящее на/в должности инспектора»?

Answer (score 4):

Лучше, чтобы лицо не "состояло" в должности инспектора, а РАБОТАЛО в должности инспектора.

Answer (score 2):

Если отталкиваться от значения (*служебное место, связанное с определённым кругом обязанностей и полномочий*), то стоит употреблять предлог *"на"*.
В прессе чуть чаще используется другой предлог. Например, на не очень уважаемой здесь Википедии  есть определение: "инаугурация — церемония вступления в должность", то есть лицо в итоге *состоит в должности*, а не на должности.
Возможно, здесь допустимы оба варианта, хотя я бы употребил *"в"*.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такие выражения "снять с должности" и "назначить на должность". Пара предлогов НА - С работает здесь прекрасно. 
Но контекст даёт нам слово СОСТОЯЩЕЕ как главное по отношению к зависимому слову "должность". 
 В справочнике "Управление в русском языке" Д.Э. Розенталя читаем: "Состоять - 1. (иметь в своём составе кого-что-л.) из кого - чего. *Семья состоит из четырёх человек.* 2. (заключаться в чём-либо)в чём. *Несчастье Рудина состоит в том, что он России не знает. (Т.)*
Как видим, с предлогом НА слово СОСТОЯЩЕЕ не употребляется. Поэтому используем предлог В: "состоящее в должности". 
Только, если честно, я не понимаю, как может ЛИЦО СОСТОЯТЬ в ДОЛЖНОСТИ? Ужасное выражение.

Comment: я ответил в своем посте

Comment: В словосочетании "назначить на должность" присутствует сема стороннего действия "сверху" (назначение обычно делает вышестоящее лицо или организация). Поэтому здесь не может быть другого предлога, кроме НА. "Снять с должности" имеет к тому же и аналогию со словосочетанием "снять С поверхности". Что касается глагола СОСТОЯТЬ то есть случай, когда он употребляется с предлогом НА: состоять на учете [ТУТ](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_304964).

Comment: > В словосочетании "назначить на должность" присутствует сема стороннего действия "сверху" ... Поэтому здесь не может быть другого предлога...

С прелогом согласен, с аргументацией - отнюдь. Не думаю, что сложившееся "назначить на" стоит объяснять какими-то геометрическими соображениями. Они и в прямых значениях весьма слабо действеют, а уж тут выбор предлога ьносить весьма и весьма условный характер. Сравните: отправили в командировку, но на войну. И еще "утвердили в должности"... Никакой видимой общей закономерности.

Comment: Я не имею в виду, что эта сема главная. Но она есть.

Comment: А я именно о том, что её не может быть в принципе. "Главная - не главная" тут не проходит. Только способность глагола сочетаться с тем или иным предлогом.

Answer (score 1):

Лицо, состоящее в должности инспектора.

Answer (score 1):

Тык: [Какой предлог написать?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

> Только, если честно, я не понимаю, как может ЛИЦО СОСТОЯТЬ в ДОЛЖНОСТИ? Ужасное выражение

Вот насчет "состоять в должности"... Тут исторический оборот, не всегда фиксируемый словарями... "Состоять" раньше имело более широкий круг значений, в том числе и "быть в каком-то общественном положении", "занимать какую-то вакансию" (это в "переводе" не современный, тогда таких слов и не знали): состоять при дворе, состоять секретарем у такого-то и проч. Сейчас оно сохранилось почти исключительно в выражениях типа "состоять в должности" и "состоять при полку".

[Типа так](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8185)

Comment: А как вы эти ссылки делаете? Очень хочется научиться :-))

Comment: @olsa Чтобы поставить ссылку, нужно кликнуть по иконке с глобусом или нажать Ctrl+L и вставить ссылку. Либо прописать ее в тексте как `[текст ссылки](адрес ссылки)`. Подробнее про свойства редактора можно прочитать здесь: [cинтаксис разметки](http://hashcode.ru/markdown_help/).

Comment: Спасибо. Поупражняться надо :-))

Comment: ой, неужели вы не умеете?  
Я бы вам первой давно рассказал )))

Comment: Меня тоже очень интересуют короткие ссылки типа ЗДЕСЬ. В Интернете прочитала, что нужно использовать определённую формулу. Может, проведёте ликбез по коротким ссылкам?

Comment: Не знаю что такое "короткие ссылки", но в принципе именно здесь, в данной среде все достаточно просто. Сначала в квадратных скобках пишете **как назвать**, потом в другой паре квадратных скобок - **куда послать**.
(Только в комментрариях это не работатет)

[Типа так] [1]

[1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8185